# Geckodriver executable needs to be in path on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I keep getting this error with my script that I'm trying to run on my Raspberry Pi even though I've downloaded Geckodriver and made the directory it's in (/home/pi/Desktop/geckos) part of the path. I've tried to run

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckodriverManager

driver = wd.Firefox("/home/pi/Desktop/geckos")
```

to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Having the same problem...